# Writing testable services in Symfony 2 and propel use of DiC

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to call some methods on my `MyEntityRepository`, **inside a service**. I've seen some example about injecting `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` to get needed repository:

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Service;     

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

Class MyService
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        $repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:MyEntity');

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

With this service definition:

```
my_service:
  class: Acme\HelloBundle\Service\MyService
  arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
```

**Question** is this code testable Would be better to inject `MyEntityRepository` for future testing purposes (using a mock object as repository)?

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Service;

use Acme\HelloBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository;

Class MyService
{
    private $er;

    public function __construct(MyEntityRepository $er) { $this->er = $er; }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        $repo = $this->er;

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Using:

```
my_entity_repository:
  class: Acme\HelloBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository
  factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
  factory_method: getRepository
  arguments: ['Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\MyEntity']

my_service:
  class: Acme\HelloBundle\Service\MyService
  arguments: ['@my_entity_repository']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an entity repository would be easier to mock than an entity manager, because you would have to mock getRepository to return an entity repository mock, so in both cases, you'd have to create an entity repository mock.

But this is not the only reason why the second solution is better in my opinion : your dependencies are much clearer this way, one can see what your class really needs (the entity manager other methods are not used).

Using the second solution makes the creation of your object more involving, but this is a problem the DIC can solve.